# allocate fixed memory for char array in c++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

The code below presents a 2d char array with 64 blocks.

```
char **arr= new char*[64];
for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
    arr[i] = new char[64];
}
```

But I want to have control over this array just as I can malloc fixed memory in C.

```
char **arr= malloc(sizeof(char *) * 64);
for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
    arr[i] = malloc(64);
}
```

How can I achieve it in C++?

Also, in C, we can use pointer like this:

```
Mystruct *next_entry = (Mystruct *) ((char*) slot + SIZE;
```

we can calculate the pointer address and get the next available free memory.

What do I need to do if I want to do the same thing in C++?

Comment: Your first `malloc`, is wrong anyway. Because it should be `sizeof(char *)` probably it's a typo.

Comment: `How can I achieve it in C++?` Unless I'm misreading things here, you already have achieved it.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` isn’t really all that meaningful, since it’s defined to be 1.

Comment: Although consider allocation of all 64*64 in a single block, and make pointers into the middle.  (Unless you need to free them separately for some reason)

Comment: If you want to do this the C++ way, allocate arrays (preferably using `std::vector`) of the actual type you need, and not chars and casts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need anything extra to do the same manipulations in c++, and your `new` code is equivalent to your `malloc` code

```
char **arr    = malloc(sizeof(char) * 64); equiv  char **arr    = new char*[64];
       arr[i] = malloc(64);                equiv         arr[i] = new char[64];
```

except perhaps for the probable typo in this line

```
char **arr    = malloc(sizeof(char) * 64);
```

which should read

```
char **arr= malloc(sizeof(char *) * 64);
```

also this will work just as it does in c

```
Mystruct *next_entry = (Mystruct *) ((char*) slot + SIZE;
```

although even in c, i think this violates strict aliasing rules, but I am not quite sure.

Comment: So you mean even in my code in c++ version, I can still access X bytes of Y block with arr[Y][X]? And c++ also support pointer manipulation I wrote in C? lol...Learned something...

Comment: In C++ you need to cast malloc, and also remmeber to `free` instead of `delete`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb The intention is to use `new`, and `delete` instead of `malloc`.